# rearrange two columns into single unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has two ID fields:

- ID_expired
- ID_issued

[image]

This table is the only place where this link between IDs is recorded. An ID_issued will show up with a match in these ID_expired column when a new ID_issued occurs (e.g. z234, g123).  There are some exact duplicate rows.  There are also instances where there is a duplicate ID_issued but no  ID_expired listed (e.g. b111).
My objective is to connect all the IDs into a single row so I can refer to the ID history of an individual.

[image]

Comment: Where is your data when id_expired=blank and id_issued=123? You can do this via heirarchy query

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View and add the table to the view for as many times as there are ID's and join it on itself as many times as well.